# Composition or Aggregation specific example

Tags: java, oop

I am a bit confused about the difference. I understand the basic example of houses and rooms being composition, and say geese and flock being an aggregation but I am struggling applying this to a program I am working on. It feels like I can convince myself either way.

I have two classes as below, `Publisher` and `Book`:

```
public class Publisher {

   public String name;
   public Publisher(String name)
}


public class Book {
   public String publisherName;

   public Book(Publisher pub){
   this.publisherName = pub.name;
   }

}
```

So here I am passing a `Publisher` object to instantiate a new `Book`, rather than creating this instance inside the `Book` object itself. This means that the life of that `Publisher` object is *independent* of the life of the `Book` object.

In addition, a `Publisher` is really just a collection of `Books`.

I think this means it is an Aggregation, as opposed to a Composition.

If I argue the other way in favour of Composition, I can say, the *concept* of the Book does not exist without the Publisher. This is conceptual, as opposed to being reflected in the code.

Presumably, whether it is Aggregation or Composition, depends on my code *implementation* and therefore it is Aggregation here since the `Book` object has an independent life cycle to the `Publisher` object.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Both Composition and Aggregation are the forms of association between two objects, but there is a subtle difference between composition and aggregation.

We refer association between two objects as Composition, when one class owns other classes and other classes can not meaningfully exist, when its owner is destroyed

```
public class Car {
    //final will make sure engine is initialized
    private final Engine engine;  
       
    public Car(){
        engine = new Engine();
    }
}

class Engine {
    private String type;
}
```

Aggregation means that can exist without being part of the main object.
Since Organization has Person as employees, the relationship between them is Aggregation. Here is how they look like in terms of Java classes

```
public class Organization {
    private List employees;
}

public class Person {
    private String name;   
}
```

In your case it looks like Aggregation, since both objects can exist independently.

Source: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/ifference-between-association-vs-composition-vs-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

> Presumably, whether it is Aggregation or Composition, depends on my
> code implementation and therefore it is Aggregation here since the
> Book object has an independent life cycle to the Publisher object.
>
> Is that right?

Yes, the code defines the kind of association.